# Nodejs: What does Reflect function do?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've seen `Reflect` function few times while researching through the nodejs source code in [events.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/36b13eb0e9e850fb8239327c23a2da864aabf6c9/lib/events.js#L131) module. And can't find definition of it.

Can anybody explain me what this function does?

Comment: How hard did you look?  Literally the first result for "javascript reflect" is [the mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect).

Comment: And in future, if you still need to post a question after thoroughly searching (see above) please quote the code you're asknig about. There are lots of things with similar names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is javascript Reflect.construct newTarget doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346328/what-is-javascript-reflect-construct-newtarget-doing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reflect` is a new ES6 built-in object.

`Reflect.apply(...)` will execute a function with a list of passed arguments.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/apply

Code sample

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

const result = Reflect.apply(sum, undefined, [1, 2])
console.log(result)

// Same to
const result2 = sum.apply(undefined, [1, 2])
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: it seems i need a break and relax. i thought it's nodejs function like process.binding. thank you