# What is javascript Reflect.construct newTarget doing

Tags: javascript

When Im reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct),It tells me that "A new instance of the given target, created by calling it (or newTarget, if present) as a constructor with the given arguments." But in reality, it is not the case at all. Here is an example:

```
function Parent() {
  this.parent = "Parent"
  console.log("This is parent.")
}
function Child() {
  this.child = "Child"
  console.log("This is child.")
}
var result = Reflect.construct(Parent, [], Child);
console.log(result)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

This is acting so weird to me because base on the doc, when we put Child as new target parameter in Reflect.construct, it should use constructor of Child to make a new instance, but the log shows "This is parent." is printed and property of Parent is saved while at the same time constructor is of Child(). How could this be possible? Can someone please explain what is happening behind the scene? This is driving me crazy, I really want to know how javascript does this. Thank you so much guys.

Comment: "*it should use constructor of Child to make a new instance*" - no, it only calls the constructor that you pass in as `target` (the first argument). It uses the newtarget to derive the inheritance hierarchy only. `Reflect.construct` can be used to desugar `super()` calls in `class` constructors.

Comment: Hi Bergi, I did see your answer on that page but pardon me as im super new to javascript so I don't fully understand all of it. Like the [[NewTarget]] property(does double brackets means it is an inner property/method? but i only see properties like __proto__?) cannot be found in the output graph, it makes me more confused. So base on what you said, the [[NewTarget]] holds the child constructor and eventually it makes the __proto__ point to prototype of child() right? At least thats what I get when including the output graph. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Actually I bookmarked that page since I could not fully understands your answer and hopefully one day will do.

Comment: Yes, double brackets mean that it's an internal property. In this case, an internal property of an internal object, so it's pretty much irrelevant - all that matter is that you can use the `new.target` "keyword" to access it inside a constructor's scope, similar to how you can use the `this` keyword in a function's scope. "*the [[NewTarget]] holds the child constructor and eventually it makes the instance [[prototype]] point to `child.prototype` right?*" - yes.

Comment: It is not full duplicate, it is just similar, but about Reflect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the documentation is somewhat misleadingly worded. What seems to be happening is that `construct()` invokes the first the first argument as the *constructor* (i.e. to initialize the object), but uses the last argument as the *prototype* (i.e. the actual "class" of the object). In your case, `result instanceof Child` returns true, but `result instanceof Parent` returns false.

So, the result of `Reflect.construct(target, args, newTarget)` seems to be equivalent to this:

```
var result = Object.create(newTarget.prototype);
target.apply(result, args);
```

However, there is one significant difference: in the above example, the `new.target` operator within either function will return `undefined`, since you're not using the `new` keyword to create the object. When you use `Reflect.construct()`, on the other hand, `new.target` will point to `newTarget` (hence the name, I suppose) -- probably because, in the end, the resulting object will belong to that class.

*(Note: I have since requested an edit to the MDN page about `Reflect.construct()` to include these details)*

Comment: Hi Máté Safranka, your answer is fantastic. It confused me the most actually when I saw the data structure output, cause I could not find new.target property there. Is it some kind of hidden property in the Function?

Comment: No, `new.target` is a special keyword, kind of like `this`; it's always available, and refers to different things depending on the invocation context. Specifically, it refers to the function that's currently being invoked as a constructor.

Comment: `Reflect.construct(OneClass, args, OtherClass)` === `OneClass.apply(Object.create(OtherClass.prototype), args)` ?